# What's the best file system I should use on an external hard drive that will be shared with MacOS (Big Sur) and Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, filesystem, mac, external-hdd

I want to share an external 2TB USB hard drive for backup data between my personal Mac and my work laptop which run Ubuntu.

I need to be able to read/write with both OS, even if I will use it mostly with my Mac.

I tried with exFAT but, on Ubuntu, I'm getting an error message when I try paste a file on, and with HDF+ it doesn't even let me.

What's the best file system I can use in this case?

EDIT: I didn't tried NTFS, I read it's unreliable to be used on Mac and Linux, the backup on this hard drive is quite important to me.

Comment: What does the error message say when using ExFAT from Ubuntu? Isn't it just that it cannot set permissions and ownership?

Comment: My experience, FWIW, is that I have a better experience if I format the disk on the non-linux machine.  So, I would encourage you to format your disk on your Mac, using exFat, and giving that a try.

Comment: @mivk it wasn't a permission error message or access denied, unfortunately I can't remember quite well what was the exact message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Formatting in exFAT

Mac's and Ubuntu 20.10 and above, work well with exFAT.

Ubuntu 20.04 and less require the addition of exFAT support:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt update

sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

This worked well for me, exFAT drives now mount as soon as plugged in.

I have many files over 4GB so FAT32's limit does not work for me.

### Upgrading Kernel

Kernel 5.4 and later can access the exFAT file system. A simple upgrade is probably better than a bandage.

NTFS works fine with Ubuntu but not with a MAC.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions, I formatted the drive with exFAT using Disk Utility on Mac, installed the modules you told me to on my linux laptop but when I plug it in, I hear the sound notification for plugged in device but no device appears in my file browser. `fdisk -l` result is:

`Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 125313023 125310976 59.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

Comment: @FeDos: Is it not visible in both MacOS and Ubuntu or just not visible in Ubuntu? Thus is the site I quoted the code from: https://itsfoss.com/mount-exfat/ The procedure is given on a few other sites and I have tested it, but not on a Mac.

Comment: I made a Live USB with 20.04.2 to test the above code on, but found it could already read and write exFAT okay. I am wondering if you just need to upgrade the kernel of your Ubuntu laptop to allow it to use exFAT?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, NTFS is very reliable on Linux, and there are reliable NTFS drivers for Mac to allow writing. These are not free, but not expensive either.

HFS+ can be [re-mounted read/write in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/a/348870/53547), but it is not well tested, and you will probably have to fix the ownership/permissions.

ExFAT should also work well now, even though it is a much simpler filesystem than the other 2. For simple backups of documents, that should work well.

If it's for more thorough backups, you may need to use the native filesystem anyway to preserve ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going with Mac compatibility and not any other compatibility beyond Mac and Ubuntu, your options really are just exceptionally limited:

- HFS
- HFS+
- FAT32

HFS support does not exist out of the box on Linux, but you can get it easily on Ubuntu.

---

***HFS or HFS+***

HFS or HFS+ is what you're going to want to use - it's the Mac compatible disk format, and has limited UNIX permissions so it works okay with Linux.

HFS+ is a newer version of HFS is all, but they are not the same so there's two different filesystem standards for them.

You'll need to install `hfsutils` for HFS or `hfsprogs` for HFS+ on your work laptop.  Unless you don't have superuser access, which limits us even further.

---

**FAT32: A fallback for all OSes**

If you do not have superuser on your work laptop, then your only fallbacks *guaranteed* to work will be the FAT32 filesystem which is universally readable.  It limits however how much you want to store and the largest file size it can support (4GB).

Comment: I would also add extfat as an option despite of what OP mentionned. It is currently well supported, in latest linux versions through a kernel driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both FAT32 and ExFAT/NTFS to backup files on 128 GB microSD cards and Flash drives to/from Mac OS including Big Sur and Ubuntu 20.04 for the past year, making backups 2-3 times a week utilizing USB ports on the Mac, and Lenovo laptop's USB ports and/or built-in SD card reader.

Both formats are quite capable, however until Linux really provides good ExFAT recovery tools, I'd stick with the FAT32 file system.

It's critical to verify your media on your 2 TB drive to make sure it's not counterfeit, though this is more a problem of late with flash memory,it could happen with hard disks, too.

Comment: What do you mean by counterfeit?  Do you mean bad areas on the disk that won't store data?

Comment: I mean merchandise that's of poor quality with a label of another manufacturer with fictional capacities.  It may format to 256 GB, 512 GB, or 2 TB, and appears to allow copying, but it will produce I/O errors upon re-reading the data.